# Why Typo3 website special characters are not saving to database?

Tags: database, server, typo3

I got a website to move to our server and I have successfully moved it.But I have noticed some strange thing.Site doesn't render Danish characters (only special characters).When when I try to save using htmlarea in admin section and I can save Lorem Ipsum with any issue.But special danish characters are seems saving to database but when I open htmlarea it shows nothing.

Seems me there should be some configuration or settings to do.I tried to change character set but didnt work.Then whole db and table change to Utf8.No luck.

Anyone is having an idea to fix this?
please mentioned the place and page name as I am totally newbie to typo3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

More info regarding typo3 ond utf8 you can find there - http://wiki.typo3.org/UTF-8_support (TYPO3 UTF-8 support). Which TYPO3 version you have?

Comment: Try add in the configuration file (typo3/conf/localconf.php) next strings:  

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['setDBinit'] = 'SET NAMES utf8;';  

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['forceCharset'] = 'utf-8';

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify your page typoscript configuration.

set htmlSpecialChars = 0 at the time of both entryHTMLparser_db and exitHTMLparser_db.

Use below **page typoscript configuration**. Might be your problem will be solved.

```
mod.SHARED {
    defaultLanguageFlag = de
    defaultLanguageLabel = Deutsch
}

# Classes. Do not forget to define them in the CSS class
RTE.classes {

    # lists
    checklist {
        name = Checkliste
    }

    # tables
    table {
        name = Normale Tabelle
    }
    table-condensed {
        name = Verkürzte Tabelle
    }
    table-bordered {
        name = Tabelle mit Rahmen
    }
    table-styled {
        name = Tabelle mit anderem Design
    }
    table-striped {
        name = Tabelle mit Streifen
    }
    table-hover {
        name = Tabelle mit Hover-Effekt
    }

    # aligns
    align-justify {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/htmlarea/locallang_tooltips.xml:justifyfull
    }
    align-left {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/htmlarea/locallang_tooltips.xml:justifyleft
        value = text-align: left;
    }
    align-center {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/htmlarea/locallang_tooltips.xml:justifycenter
        value = text-align: center;
    }
    align-right {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/htmlarea/locallang_tooltips.xml:justifyright
        value = text-align: right;
    }
    csc-frame-frame1 {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/contentcss/locallang.xml:frame-frame1
        value = background-color: #EDEBF1; border: 1px solid #333333;
    }
    csc-frame-frame2 {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/contentcss/locallang.xml:frame-frame2
        value = background-color: #F5FFAA; border: 1px solid #333333;
    }
    important {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/contentcss/locallang.xml:important
        value = color: #8A0020;
    }
    name-of-person {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/contentcss/locallang.xml:name-of-person
        value = color: #10007B;
    }
    detail {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/contentcss/locallang.xml:detail
        value = color: #186900;
    }
    component-items {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/contentcss/locallang.xml:component-items
        value = color: #186900;
    }
    action-items {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/contentcss/locallang.xml:action-items
        value = color: #8A0020;
    }
    component-items-ordered {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/contentcss/locallang.xml:component-items
        value = color: #186900;
    }
    action-items-ordered {
        name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/contentcss/locallang.xml:action-items
        value = color: #8A0020;
    }

    style1 {
        name = Stil 1
    }

    htmlCode {
        name = HTML Code
    }
    phpCode {
        name = PHP Code
    }

}

RTE.classesAnchor {

    externalLink {
        class = external-link
        type = url
        titleText = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/accessibilityicons/locallang.xml:external_link_titleText
    }
    externalLinkInNewWindow {
        class = external-link-new-window
        type = url
        titleText = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/accessibilityicons/locallang.xml:external_link_new_window_titleText
    }
    internalLink {
        class = internal-link
        type = page
        titleText = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/accessibilityicons/locallang.xml:internal_link_titleText
    }
    internalLinkInNewWindow {
        class = internal-link-new-window
        type = page
        titleText = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/accessibilityicons/locallang.xml:internal_link_new_window_titleText
    }
    download {
        class = download
        type = file
        titleText = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/accessibilityicons/locallang.xml:download_titleText
    }
    mail {
        class = mail
        type = mail
        titleText = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/res/accessibilityicons/locallang.xml:mail_titleText
    }


    more-link {
        class = more-link
        type = page
        titleText = LLL:EXT:fluxtemplate/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:more_link_titleText
        altText = LLL:EXT:fluxtemplate/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:more_link_altText
    }
    button-link {
        class = btn
        type = page
        titleText = LLL:EXT:fluxtemplate/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:more_link_titleText
        altText = LLL:EXT:fluxtemplate/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:more_link_altText
    }
    next-link {
        class = ym-button ym-next
        type = page
        titleText = LLL:EXT:fluxtemplate/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:next_link_titleText
        altText = LLL:EXT:fluxtemplate/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:next_link_altText
    }
    back-link {
        class = back-link
        type = page
        titleText = LLL:EXT:fluxtemplate/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:back_link_titleText
        altText = LLL:EXT:fluxtemplate/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:back_link_altText
    }
}

RTE.default {

    showButtons = *
    ## Enable the image button
    showButtons := addToList(image)

    defaultContentLanguage = de


    // Make possible to read classes from the contentCSS CSS file
    buttons.textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses >

    buttons.textstyle.tags.REInlineTags >
    buttons.textstyle.REInlineTags >
    buttons.blockstyle.tags.table.allowedClasses >
    buttons.blockstyle.tags.p.allowedClasses >

    buttons.blockstyle.tags.div.allowedClasses = align-left, align-center, align-right
    buttons.blockstyle.tags.div.allowedClasses := addToList(csc-frame-frame1, csc-frame-frame2)
    buttons.blockstyle.tags.table.allowedClasses = csc-frame-frame1, csc-frame-frame2
    buttons.blockstyle.tags.td.allowedClasses = align-left, align-center, align-right
    buttons.textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses = important, name-of-person, detail




    contentCSS = typo3conf/ext/fluxtemplate/Resources/Public/CSS/rte.css

    buttons.formatblock.prefixLabelWithTag = 1
    buttons.link.relAttribute.enabled = 1
    buttons.link.queryParametersSelector.enabled = 1
    buttons.link.properties.class.allowedClasses = external-link, external-link-new-window, internal-link, internal-link-new-window, download, mail 
    buttons.link.page.properties.class.default = internal-link
    buttons.link.url.properties.class.default = external-link-new-window
    buttons.link.file.properties.class.default = download
    buttons.link.mail.properties.class.default = mail
    buttons.image.properties.class.allowedClasses = img-responsive
    // Disable contextual menu
    contextMenu.disabled = 1

    // Display status bar
    showStatusBar = 1

    //More toolbar options
    keepButtonGroupTogether = 1

    // Use CSS formatting when possible
    useCSS = 1

    // Make rtehtmlarea resizable
    rteResize = 1



    proc {


        allowedClasses = external-link, external-link-new-window, internal-link, internal-link-new-window, download, mail
        allowedClasses := addToList(detail,align-left, align-center, align-right, align-justify, csc-frame-frame1, csc-frame-frame2, component-items, action-items, component-items-ordered, action-items-ordered, important, name-of-person, indent, img-responsive)   

        allowedClasses  < RTE.default.classesCharacter
        # auskommentieren, damit klassen eingelesen werden können
        #allowedClasses := addToList( dimmed,highlight,box,info,success,warning,error,float-left,float-right,center,align-left,align-center,align-right,align-justify,style1 )

        ## TAGS ALLOWED OUTSIDE P & DIV
        allowTagsOutside := addToList( pre, img )

        allowTags := addToList( pre )

        // Tags allowed in Typolists
        allowTagsInTypolists = br,font,b,i,u,a,img,span

        // Keep unknown tags
        dontRemoveUnknownTags_db = 1

        // Allow tables
        preserveTables = 1

        entryHTMLparser_db = 1
        entryHTMLparser_db {

            // Tags allowed
            allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags

            // Tags denied
            denyTags >

            // HTML special characters
            htmlSpecialChars = 0

            // Allow IMG tags
            tags.img >

            // Additionnal attributes for P & DIV
            tags.div.allowedAttribs = class,style,align
            tags.p.allowedAttribs = class,style,align

            // Tags to remove
            removeTags = center, font, o:p, sdfield, strike, u

            // Keep non matched tags
            keepNonMatchedTags = protect
        }

        // HTML parser
        HTMLparser_db {

            // Strip attributes
            noAttrib = br

            // XHTML compliance
            xhtml_cleaning = 1
        }

        // Exit HTML parser
        exitHTMLparser_db = 1
        exitHTMLparser_db {

            // Remap bold and italic
            tags.b.remap = strong
            tags.i.remap = em

            // Keep non matched tags
            keepNonMatchedTags = 1

            // HTML special character
            htmlSpecialChars = 0
        }


    }

}


RTE.default.FE < RTE.default
RTE.default.FE.showButtons < RTE.default.showButtons
RTE.default.FE.proc.allowTagsOutside < RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside
RTE.default.FE.proc.entryHTMLparser_db.tags.img >

// PageTSConfig
TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout.altLabels  {
    0 = H1 (Default)
    1 = H1
    2 = H2
    3 = H3
    4 = H4
    5 = H5
}
```

Comment: I tried but no luck.When I save danish letters using htmlarea it saves them in to db but not showing in front end and htmlarea.Plain English is working without any issues

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem in my another project.

First set default_charset to utf8 in your php.ini file.

or you can manuaaly set it with below PHP code:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf8');
```